# Map multiple columns from pandas DataFrame into one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame as follows:

```
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
```

I have a dictionary whose keys are tuples of the pandas DataFrame columns e.g.

```
{(1, 3) : 5, (2, 4) : 6}
```

I want to a create a new column in the pandas DataFrame e.g. `df['c']` based on this mapping. **What is the best way to do this?**

So the final DataFrame should be:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  3  5
1  2  4  6
```

Answer (score 4):

Given your `DataFrame`, and your `dict`, you could `list` and `zip` which converts to `tuple`, then `map` your d:

```
df['c'] = pd.Series(list(zip(df.a,df.b))).map(d)

   a  b  c
0  1  3  5
1  2  4  6
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) along `axis=1` to aggregate into `tuple`, then [`pandas.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) the mappings and assign it to column `c`:

```
>>> d = {(1, 3) : 5, (2, 4) : 6}
>>> df['c'] = df.agg(tuple, 1).map(d)
>>> df
   a  b  c
0  1  3  5
1  2  4  6
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with `Series` constructor - keys are converted to `MultiIndex`:

```
d = {(1, 3) : 5, (2, 4) : 6}

df1 = df.join(pd.Series(d,name='c'), on=['a','b'])
print (df1)
   a  b  c
0  1  3  5
1  2  4  6
```

**Detail**:

```
print (pd.Series(d,name='c'))
1  3    5
2  4    6
Name: c, dtype: int64
```